# Word for using something good for an evil/bad purpose?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a man using pleasing words and kindness to use a lady for his selfish reasons.

Kindness in itself is good.
But it is being used for a bad purpose/evil intention.

I thought of deception or trickery but neither seem to fit quite exactly.

Comment: One might say it’s been/being ***corrupted***.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence where the word would be used.

Comment: Your example is flattery, not kindness.

Comment: The question posed in the title is far more general than what is suggested by the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjectives "*treacherous*" and "*perfidious*" can be used, since they imply that the persons so qualified are likely to do wrong to people because of their lies, that is, they cannot be trusted; however if lies such as the pretense to be good are covered by this characteristic, these words do not specifically mean "that cannot be trusted because they only pretend to be good while they are in fact evil-minded".

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/treacherous?q=treacherous)) **treacherous** adjective /ˈtretʃərəs/ ​that cannot be trusted; intending to harm you
> SYNONYM deceitful
> ♦ He was weak, cowardly, and treacherous.
> ♦ lying, treacherous words

In order to get your point across precisely, you have to exert your command of the language and come up with telling phrases.

*For instance*

- He is treacherous in a peculiar sort of way; he insinuates himself into your affection through a display of caring that is nothing but fake.

This is nothing but an example, and all sorts of variants and alternative possibilities will do, each proper to a particular case; it is your responsibility as a writer or speaker to come up with that that will be exactly what you feel is true.

Answer (score 1):

Exploitation, perversion, manipulation, desecration, defiling, corruption.
Source: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/perversion.html#C0-3  (Third definition and fourth definitions)

Answer (score -3):

It's called "narcissism". In the beginning 'love bombing' occurs even though it's just a ploy. Psychologically speaking, the narcissists is relentless until THEY are stopped. The 'gaslighting' mind fuckery that the victim goes through could be likened to detriment seen in ptsd. Research 'narcissist' and you will have your thesaurus!

Comment: This would benefit from a reference.  As it stands this sounds more like a comment than an answer.  I encourage you to take the site [tour] and see the [help] for more information.